# Getting True/False expression error in my DAX formula and don't know why?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have the following DAX formula attempting to retrieve the URL of a player with the largest Total Distance value based on criteria, however my formula keeps getting a True/False expression error.

My formula below was as follows:

```
Player_With_Largest_Distance_URL = 
VAR LargestPlayer =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Catapult - CTR'[Player Name] ),
        MAXX (
            SUMMARIZE (
                'Catapult - CTR',
                'Catapult - CTR'[Player Name],
                "PlayerTotal",
                CALCULATE (
                    SUM ( 'Catapult - CTR'[Total Distance (m)] ),
                    'Catapult - CTR'[Period Category] <> "Session",
                    'Catapult - CTR'[Period Category] <> "Rehab Session",
                    'Catapult - CTR'[Period Category] <> "Extras",
                    NOT ( CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Catapult - CTR'[Period Category], "Rest" ) ),
                    NOT (
                        'Catapult - CTR'[Player Name]
                            IN CALCULATETABLE (
                                VALUES ( 'Catapult - CTR'[Player Name] ),
                                'Catapult - CTR'[Period Category] = "Rehab Session"
                            )
                    )
                )
            ),
            [PlayerTotal]
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        ISBLANK(LargestPlayer),
        BLANK(),
        CALCULATE (
            VALUES ( 'Catapult - CTR'[Photo URL] ),
            'Catapult - CTR'[Player Name] = LargestPlayer
        )
    )
```

I can't work out what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more info about your issue ?